# requirejs + backbonejs + optimizer = backbone undefined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

Backbone doesn't get called in the indexview module.

using requirejs 2.1.5/2.1.4 and backbonejs 0.9.10

main.js after running r.js

```
...
// this is causing the backbone to return 
// null/undefined in the next define call below
define("backbone", function(){}); 

define('views/index/IndexView', [
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'text!templates/index/indexTemplate.html'  
], function(_, Backbone, indexTemplate){

    console.log(Backbone); // returns undefined
    var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
...
```

BUT if I take out the first define call that registers backbone as a module, everything
works fine. but backbone-min.js gets loaded separately. but for now it's the only way
to make the script run. I am definitely missing something here.

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        underscore  : 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone    : 'libs/backbone/backbone-min'
        templates   : '../templates'
    },
    shim: {        
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});

require(['app'], function(App){
    App.initialize();
});
```

**build.js**

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "../../build",
    optimize: "none",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "libs/requirejs/require-jquery",
        "underscore" : 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        "backbone": 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        "templates": '../templates',
    },
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main",
            exclude: ["jquery"]
        }
    ]    
})
```

I'm still getting my feet wet with backbone and requirejs. 
any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: It must be apart of your config.  In my build, the require block looks like this:
define("backbone", ["jquery","underscore"], (function (global) {
    return function () {
        var ret, fn;
        return ret || global.Backbone;
    };
}(this)));

note, I also have underscore in my shim.js

Comment: Can you add `mainConfigFile` to your build.js file like the following: `mainConfigFile: 'app/main.js'` then rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need that define('backbone',...). What is that part for anyways? You don't need to define Backbone as a module. Requirejs is doing the job of making Backbone available for you to use throughout your framework. As you can see in your code, by calling Backbone.View.extend(), Backbone already exists. If you want to inspect it, don't use console.log, use console.dir instead. In the chrome inspector it formats the output nicely.

Secondly, add underscore to the backbone deps array in your shim.

Comment: the define('backbone',...) is generated automatically by the optimizer script. that's also what I noticed in the require-jquery tutorial on the requirejs site.

Comment: also, underscore is already registered as a dependency in my shim.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this issue, you need to add the 'shim' from your main.js to your build.js file, and will work like a charm ;)